# Interpreting the best-fit student t distribution (based on maximum likelihood estimation) for my datasets

Tags: probability, distributions, maximum-likelihood, goodness-of-fit, t-distribution

I have fitted (through maximum likelihood estimation of parameters) a number of leptokurtic probability density functions (i.e.

- logistic
- hyperbolic-secant
- Laplace
- log-logistic
- student's t (with parameters $\nu, \mu$)
- gamma
- Weibull
- Cauchy
- Levy
- Gumbel)

to two datasets that are measured at different times and have different sample sizes.

All are 2-parameter PDFs. The Student's t distribution is the best fit PDF in terms of the highest log-likelihood values for both datasets. The second best-fitting PDF has the AIC difference of more than 6.

1. Intuitively speaking, what are the unique properties of the student's t distribution that differentiate it from the other leptokurtic PDFs (at least from the one listed here.)
2. How should I interpret/explain that why the student's t distribution is the best-fitting PDF and the others are not?

Comment: Why do you think, that student t is a 2-parameter PDF? I would say, that it is a one-parameter PDF.

Comment: @Fredi if parametrized by location $\mu$ and degrees of freedom $\nu$ it obviously has two parameters.

Comment: The one-parameter student's t is extended with a [location parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location_parameter) because the mode of the datasets' bell-shaped histogram is away from zero. So it has two parameters now: the degrees-of-freedom $\nu$ and the location parameter $\mu$.